# What am I doing wrong when trying to create an object from an array using file input

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently learning Java OOP and having difficulty understanding why I continue get an error.

My Boat class is as follows:

```
//Boats

 public class Boats {
 String Name;
 int age;
 int length;


Boats(String Name){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.age = age;
    this. length = length;
} 

public void setName(String name){
   this.Name = name;
}



public void returnBoatInfo(){
    System.out.println("Boat "+Name+" is"+age+" years old "+" and "+length+" feet long");
   }

}
```

When I try to declare it as an object array and use a file to create new objects. It does not appear that any objects are ever created. 
Main is as follows:

```
//Main

      Boats[] fleet = new Boats[3];
      Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("boats.txt"));

      /*
      fleet[0] = new Boats("Destiny",25,30);
      fleet[1] = new Boats("Sea Monkey",15,25);
      fleet[2] = new Boats("Morning Star",35,42);
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        fleet[i].returnBoatInfo();
      //this works
      }
      */

      for(int i = 0;fleet.length<i;i++){
          fleet[i].Name = new Boats(readFile.nextLine());
          fleet[i].returnBoatInfo();
          System.out.println("File has been read "+ readFile.nextLine());
          break;
      }
```

If I try to loop through and print off the statement returnBoatInfo for each object I never get anything. I'm certain I'm missing something here, any help to understand that is better would very appreciated.

Comment: Change your for-loop condition to `i < fleet.length`

Comment: In the line `fleet[i].Name = new Boats(readFile.nextLine());` you're Essentially doing `fleet[i].Name = new Boats("some string in file" );`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately if I update my condition I then receive an error message:                                                                                            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: practicemakesperfect.Boats cannot be converted to java.lang.String
 at practicemakesperfect.PracticeMakesPerfect.main(PracticeMakesPerfect.java:35)
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

> fleet[i].Name = new Boats(readFile.nextLine());

`fleet[i].Name` is a String, and `new Boats(readFile.nextLine())` is a Boat object.

Try this:

```
fleet[i].Name = readFile.nextLine();
```

`readFile.nextLine()` will return a String, so you can use it to populate `Name` attribute.

Also, change your condition as mentioned in comments.